# List (Of String) figuring out Database column values

Tags: vb.net, string, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have some data in DB, which i am getting using a WebService in  a List(Of String) and returning that List using following code

```
    Public Function getDetails() As List(Of String)
        Dim Connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim Command As SqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim DataReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing

        Try
            Dim MyList As New List(Of String)

            Connection = New SqlConnection("Connection String")
            Connection.Open()
            Command = New SqlCommand("select * from TBL", Connection)
            DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()

            While (DataReader.Read)
                MyList.Add(DataReader("Col1"))
                MyList.Add(DataReader("Col2"))
                MyList.Add(DataReader("Col3"))
                MyList.Add(DataReader("Col4"))

            End While

            If MyList.Count <> 0 Then
                Return MyList
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            DataReader.Close()
            Connection.Close()
        End Try
End Function
```

Now i have a VB.net program in which i m utilizing the web service and getting the values using the code below

```
Dim webQuery As QueryWebService.Service = New QueryWebService.Service


    Dim queryDetails As String()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    queryDetails = webQuery.getStudentQuery()

    While i < queryDetails.Length
        txtQuery.Text = txtQuery.Text + " " + queryDetails.GetValue(i)
        i = i + 1
    End While
```

Values are fine but they are in a single String() and i want to show the values of each column in a different TextField(Multiline), how can i do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning a list but your queryDetails is an array.  Try making queryDetails a list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if i change it to list i get an error. For example if i change it to this `Dim queryDetails As List(Of String)` i get this error "value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)"